# Get window width and send as variable to flask

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, flask

I'm trying to set the window width as a variable that will be sent along with some input text on-click to my back-end Flask program. The window width variable will determine which block of code will execute in Python. I've found information about how to get the window width of the screen that a site is being viewed on. I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how to pass it back to Flask.

I want to use an If statement that basically says "If the width is 425px or less, set the variable and pass it with submit. Else, do nothing."

I've started with something along the lines of:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width()
if($(windowWidth) <= 425 {
    $(function(){.....}
```

This is what I have that listens for a click on my form submit button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#submitButton").click(function() {
           $("#mainForm").submit();
       });
    });
```

I just need to stick them together somehow.

Any help is greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax call for backend api calling
Calling api doesn't matter backend-built frameworks. Suppose backend was built with one of PHP, Python, Node and Java. But declaring api endpoints is same.
For example, every websites have their own backends but api formats are all same like below
abc.com/api1 
ex.com/api2
...

So you can do like this
First get width and with if statement is true, you can call api
        // Returns width of browser viewport
        var browserWidth = $( window ).width();

```
    // Returns width of HTML document
    var domWidth = $( document ).width();
    // you can select one of these following your condition

    if (browserWidth <= 425) {
        $.ajax ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'yourbackend/apiurl',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'data' : "data",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log ("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope this help you

Comment: Could I just put domWidth in with the mainForm submit? Ex: $("#mainForm", domWidth).submit(). Just curious if that would work.

Comment: No you can't. Form data can be submitted automatically by "name"

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get this working exactly how I wanted. But I did find a work around. If the relevant screen size is detected, it will redirect to '/mobile'. I can then make that the same as the main landing page, but with proper CSS for rendering on a mobile device.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       if($(window).width() <= 425) {
       window.location = "/mobile";
        }
     });
    </script>
```